# JavaScript variable: add the values returned by functions and then multiply them by the value returned by another function

Tags: javascript, variables

```
var totalPrice = (getOne() + getTwo()) * getThree();
```

Is there a reason why this doesn't work? I've googled away but I don't think I understand what I'm doing enough to use useful search terms. I tried without the brackets, just as a test, to see if it would at least multiply the last two functions and add the first. That didn't even work so I guess the problem lays within the `*` operator.

Thanks,
Jo

EDIT: Thanks guys, it looks like I was missing an 's' in one of my functions. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: what do you mean by multiplying functions? you mean what they return (return values)?

Comment: Did you make sure that all three functions return a valid result?

Comment: what do your functions return?

Comment: works perfect here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hYdE/ you may missed the return values?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? What happens? Do you get any errors in the console? My guess is you're not returning a Number from at least one of the functions, and `totalPrice` ends up as `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on how you defined your functions: e.g.

```
function getOne() { return 1; }
function getTwo() { return 2; }
function getThree() { return 3; }

var totalPrice = (getOne() + getTwo()) * getThree();
console.log(totalPrice); // 9
```

Maybe you're not returning a value with `return`

Comment: Whoops, I went through the functions beforehand but I must have missed one error: the last function was missing an s. 

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Here's a jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/CxD84/

Maybe the problem comes from one of your function return, like in this jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/3eRCn/1/